# Do Business Intelligence projects support custom default templates?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

In visual studio 2012, I create new report server projects using the default template below:

[image]

When the project is created, it specifies the following build/deployment settings in the configuration:

[image]

Obviously these settings are not appropriate for my environment, so I find myself changing them manually every time I create a new report server project.

Is there any way I can change these settings in the default project template so that they will be automatically populated whenever I create a new report?

EDIT: I tried what Reed suggested, but the option was greyed out. Does this indicate that BI projects don't support default templates? If not, how can I create a new custom template for a report server project?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to create a [custom project template for VS 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx) with these defaults modified.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried that (added shared data sources and changed build settings), but the "Export Template" button option is disabled on the file menu. Any ideas?

Comment: @Mansfield Nope - that should work, though I haven't done much with reporting projects, so that may be an issue.

Comment: I see. Googling a little seems to indicate that option is only supported for certain project types; reports may not be one of them.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your environment and your workflow. The below is my personal preference and is a potential solution to your issue:

I tend to use a single report project solution for all my SSRS development, but only for the reports being worked on at that time. It contains all the shared datasets I use for live and test environments and all other settings are as I need.

When ready for deployment, I move the rdl into source control and deploy from there, deleteing the rdl from the project in the process. This helps to keep syncronisation between live reports, source control and filesystem.

In my experience, its far too easy for someone to accidentally modify and deploy an older version of a report from a shared directory.

It will enable you to have the settings you need when you create a new report, as you will not be creating another solution.

Comment: Interesting. What steps do you take if you have to make changes to a report after initial deployment?

Comment: I check it out of source control and add it to the project. The data sources are set up already so I can do what I need, then save, check in and deploy through report manager using 'replace'. I don't use report parts or custom dll files so this works for me.